# Can't find backface culling setting in version 2.78

Tags: edit-mode

I'm using version 2.78c and I just noticed I 'lost' the backface culling setting (I haven't used it in a little while). I can't post a screenshot of the shading area in the properties panel (blender render mode only), but the only check boxes available are:

1. Textures
2. Shadows
3. Subsurface scattering
4. Environment map
5. Ray tracing
6. World space shading (which is unchecked by default).

There's also a drop-down for alpha, which I'm leaving at the default.

Every entry brought up in Google says 'Turn in on the in the shading area' - but it's not there and I can't find anything in user preferences that might control it's availability. Where has it moved to? I need to be able to check normals, and tasks like that.

Thanks in advance,
Frank Alviani

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> key while in **3D View port** (hover mouse there) and you will find **Shading** tab close to the bottom of this panel, which will show on the right side of the view port.

[image]

### Edit:

Honestly I didn't ever paid attention that both of them panels are called 'Properties'.

The one you are looking for is here (from your screenshot):

[image: yours]

Comment: The shading panel no longer looks like that in **2.78**. :( As I mentioned above, neither backface culling nor ambient occlusion is an option. The options I have available are listed in the original post. That's why I posted - and I can't find any mention anywhere of when the panel changed. Thanks, though.

Comment: @FrankAlviani This is from 2.78c. Blender Render.

Comment: @FrankAlviani also I've upvoted your question so you can add screen shot now.

Comment: OK, I saved a screenshot to share: ![shading](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZdHKvZYuPdXCXVhu0BMwxsoSMjpLzw8Fxy) - I hope this makes it easier to understand. The changelogs don't say anything about this change...

Comment: I messed up the link - here's another one that hopefully helps: ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/jQx86i8.png) - thanks for your patience.

Comment: @FrankAlviani Could you please upload whole Blender window screenshot?

Comment: OK - I'll have it up in just a few minutes. Thanks for continuing with this :)

Comment: Here's the entire screen: ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/Nt6QFBI.png) By the way, how do I put this in so it's embedded rather than just a link? (Another noob question :( )

Comment: @FrankAlviani check my Edit.